# Delgator's delegate property points to two Delegators and not to the Delegate class

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have the following class which conforms to a protocol `SentenceDelegate`

```
class SentenceMarkov : SentenceDelegate{

  var UltimateSentence : Sentence {
    didSet { UltimateSentence.sentenceDelegate = self}
  }
  var PenultimateSentence : Sentence 

  init(Ult : Sentence, Penult : Sentence){
    self.UltimateSentence = Ult
    self.PenultimateSentence = Penult
  }


  func startChain(){
    self.PenultimateSentence.sentenceDelegate = self
    self.PenultimateSentence.start()
  }

  func sentenceDidFinish(){
    self.nextSentence(self.UltimateSentence.type, penUltType:  self.PenultimateSentence.type)
  }

  //etc.
}
```

I define the `SentenceDelegate` as follows:

```
protocol SentenceDelegate: class{
  func sentenceDidFinish()
 }
```

Finally, my Delegator class, `Sentence` is defined as follows:

```
class Sentence : NSObject {
  var type=""
  var eventArray:[SoundEvent] = []


  weak var sentenceDelegate: SentenceDelegate? 

  weak var soundEventDelegate: SoundEventDelegate? = nil {
    didSet {
        eventArray.forEach() {$0.delegate = soundEventDelegate}
    }
  }

  init(type :String){
   //etc.
  }


  func sentenceDone(){
    sentenceDelegate?.sentenceDidFinish() //This is where the program breaks
  }

  func start(){
    self.playEvent(0)
  }

  func handleTimer(timer: NSTimer) {
    guard let index = timer.userInfo as? Int else { return }
    playEvent(index)
  }

  func playEvent(eventIndex : Int){
    if (eventIndex < 2){
        let currEvent = self.eventArray[eventIndex]
        currEvent.startEvent()
        let nextIndex = eventIndex + 1
        SharingManager.sharedInstance.globalTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(currEvent.duration, target: self, selector: Selector("handleTimer:"), userInfo: NSNumber(integer: nextIndex), repeats: false)
    }
    else if (eventIndex==2){
        let currEvent = self.eventArray[eventIndex]
        currEvent.startEvent()
        SharingManager.sharedInstance.globalTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(currEvent.duration, target: self, selector: Selector("sentenceDone"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    else{
        //Nothing
    }
  }
}
```

I initialize the above to class and start the program from my `ViewController` in the following fashion:

```
    let s1:Sentence = Sentence(type: "S3")
    let s2:Sentence = Sentence(type: "S1")
    var newModel = SentenceMarkov(Ult: s1, Penult: s2)
    newModel.startChain()
```

When I run the program it does not execute the `SentenceDelegate` method `sentenceDidFinish` on the Delegate class. When I set a break point to that method, the program never stops. When I set a breakpoint on `sentenceDone` in the Delegator class, I inspect the `self` variable, and see that `sentenceDelegate` is defined, but points to two copies of the Delegator class (`UltimateSentence` and `PenultimateSentence`) and not the Delegate class. Furthermore, that these two instances of the Delegator class, upon using the breakpoint inspection, have `sentenceDelegate` properties which are `nil`.

Confer with photos:

[image]

[image]
I don't understand how the `Sentence` property `sentenceDelegate` (which his set to `self` in *SentenceMarkov* ) points to a sentence and not the Delegate class which calls `sentenceDidFinish`. Any elucidation of my errors in reasoning / programming would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `didSet` in conjunction with `init`. These methods are not called during `init`, so you would need to create a specific method and call that within the `init` as well. For example;

```
var UltimateSentence : Sentence {
  didSet { setDelegate() }
}

func setDelegate() {
  UltimateSentence.sentenceDelegate = self
}

init(Ult : Sentence, Penult : Sentence){
  self.UltimateSentence = Ult
  self.PenultimateSentence = Penult
  setDelegate()
}
```

You are also only keeping a weak reference to the delegates. It's not clear to me what has a strong reference to them. If nothing has a strong reference they will be destroyed once out of scope. You could confirm this by putting a `print` inside the `deinit` of `SentenceMarkov`.
It's also worth noting that the Swift standard is for classes to start with an uppercase letter and instances to start with lower case. It makes it harder to read for people used to this convention, when your instances start with upper case.

Comment: Question, what if I also need to set `penultimateSentence`'s delegate. Should I create another method specific to that?

Comment: Yes, definitely call them from the `init`

Comment: please note that the current code doesn't set up the `delegate` on `init()` but rather sets it up in `startChain` (for Penultimate) sentence

Comment: but I specifically tried exactly what you had suggested and it still does not hit the `sentenceDidFinish` method of the Delegate

Comment: See my update - what holds a strong reference to the `SentenceMarkov` instance?

Comment: so i just write `strong` in front of the `sentenceDelegate` variable declaration in the class `Sentence`?

Comment: Just remove `weak`. However, if object A has a non-weak reference to object B, which also has a non-weak reference back to A, then neither will ever destroy (circular reference). That's why `weak` exists - so one of them can be weak. In your case, it doesn't look like anything has a strong (non-weak) reference.

Comment: Well basically I only need the `sentenceDelegate` reference of the `ultimateSentence` to be active except at the beginning when I start with penUltimateSentence. After that, I swap penultimate with ultimate and have ultimate set to a new `Sentence`. From that point on only one object (ultimateSentence) needs a valid reference back to `SentencMarkov`. Does this require making something that was originally `weak`, `strong`?

Comment: or should I just set, once performing the swap, `penultimateSentence.sentenceDelegate` to `nil`?

Comment: Whatever is creating SentenceMarkov should keep a non-weak reference to it for as long as it is needed. Then the delegate references can be weak.